# Where are these values set?

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a footer with icon (svgs) links to social media and I have asked to add another link for Instagram.

This is the code in the footer:

```
<div class="footer-primary-social">
                <?php
                    $social_twitter = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('social_link_twitter')->getValue('plain');
                    $social_facebook = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('social_link_facebook')->getValue('plain');
                    $social_pinterest = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('social_link_pinterest')->getValue('plain');
                    $social_linkedin = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('social_link_linkedin')->getValue('plain');
                    $social_youtube = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('social_link_youtube')->getValue('plain');
                    $social_google_plus = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('social_link_google_plus')->getValue('plain');
                ?>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $social_facebook; ?>"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i>Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $social_pinterest; ?>"><i class="icon-social-pinterest"></i>Pinterest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $social_linkedin; ?>"><i class="icon-social-linkedin"></i>LinkedIn</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $social_youtube; ?>"><i class="icon-social-youtube"></i>YouTube</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $social_twitter; ?>"><i class="icon-social-twitter"></i>Twitter</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I found where the .svgs are kept on the server, but I don't know where the social_link_ are set so I can add a new one.  Where would I find that?

Thanks

Comment: are you using any exttension?

Comment: if yes then please let me know thek developer name (company)

Comment: I did not setup the website ( it was setup a few years ago),  don't think its an extension, can't see anything under "Disable Modules Output" that had social in the title.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom variables

https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/cms/variables-custom.html

To create a custom variable:

1. On the Admin menu, select System > Custom Variable.
2. Click the Add New Variable button.
3. Enter an identifier in the Variable Code field. Use all lowercase characters, without spaces.
4. Enter a Variable Name, which is used for internal reference. Then, do one of the following:
   In the Variable HTML Value text field, enter any content you want to include, using basic HTML tags. This option allows you to format the value.
   In the Variable Plain Value field, enter the variable value as plain text.
5. When complete, click the Save button.

Comment: That's where they are, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add New Custom Variable or change value of Existing Variable by

```
$variable = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('social_link_twitter');

if(is_null($variable)){
   Mage::getModel('core/variable')
       ->setCode('social_link_twitter)
       ->setName('Twitter Link')
       ->setPlainValue("www.twitter.com")
       ->setHtmlValue("YOUR HTML VALUE")
       ->save();
}else{
   $variable->setPlainValue("www.twitter.com\new_link")
         ->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping to find where the rest are set to keep everything the same way, but if I can't do that I will try you answer.

Comment: accept my answer if it is working for you... Happy Coding ;)

Comment: I gave you an upvote as it is a solution, but Dominic answer is where the other social media links are, so answers my question perfectly